# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' in python 3.4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import operator
def start(url):
    word_list =[]
    source_code =requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
    for post_string in soup.find_all('a',{'class':'cb-skin-ads-link'}):
        content = post_string.string
        words = content.lower()
        for each_word in words:
             print(each_word)
             word_list.append(each_word)

start('http://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/16445/gl-vs-rcb-qualifier-1-indian-premier-league-2016')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shera/PycharmProjects/Begin/wordcount.py", line 15, in <module>
    start('http://www.cricbuzz.com/live-cricket-scorecard/16445/gl-vs-rcb-qualifier-1-indian-premier-league-2016')
  File "C:/Users/Shera/PycharmProjects/Begin/wordcount.py", line 10, in start
    words = content.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `content` is not a `string` ...

Comment: There is no text in that anchor tag so what are you actually trying to parse?

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is going on, we should take a look at the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string). There is a case when `.string` would be `None`:

> If a tag contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should refer to, so .string is defined to be None

You should look into using [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) instead that would take into account the children of an element as well:

```
content = post_string.get_text()
```

Note that this would help to avoid the error, but you would still get no output since the element you find really does not have any text:

```
<a target="_blank" href="Javascript:void(0)" class="cb-skin-ads-link cb-skin-ads-link-fixed ad-skin" rel="noreferrer"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, **content** is **None**.  Try a debugger or print statements to see what you're getting from **soup.find_all**.  It seems that the list isn't empty, but the **string** attribute of at least one element is None.

Comment: After your edit, the post has too much code and not enough explanation for me to be able to add the "beautifulsoup" tag - can you add it?