# Python BeautifulSoup 'Slice' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python, email, beautifulsoup, imaplib

I have this script that runs to pull data from emails that come to the inbox, however it was working a couple days ago but now when I run it, it gives me an error whenever an email comes in "Slice Object has no attribute Lower" and says that the error is occuring at the `soup = BeautifulSoup(msg, "html.parser")` line. What does this mean and how do I go about fixing it? Here is the code:

```
import email
import imaplib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import sys

username = 'xx.xxx@xxx.ca'
password = 'xx'

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap-mail.outlook.com')
(retcode, capabilities) = mail.login(username, password)
mail.select('inbox')

n=0
while True:
    (retcode, messages) = mail.search(None, 'UNSEEN', '(SUBJECT "xxxx-    ")', '(FROM "xx.xx@xxxx.ca")')
    if retcode == 'OK':
        for num in messages[0].split():
            n=n+1
            print('Processing Email ' + str(n))
            typ, data = mail.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
            for response_part in data:
                if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                    original = email.message_from_bytes(response_part[1])
                    print("Subject: " + original['Subject'])
                    body = data[0][1]
                    msg = email.message_from_bytes(body)
                    content = msg.get_payload(decode=True)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(msg, "html.parser")
                    text = soup.get_text()
                    fontdef, email1 = text.split('-->')
                    email2, signature =     email1.split('________________________________________________')
                    print(email2)
                    typ, data = mail.store(num,'+FLAGS','\\Seen')
                    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, please include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format as code.

Comment: I assume a malformed **HTML** body. Dump `msg` into a file and inspect it. Relevant: [attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-lower-in-python-3-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422580/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-lower-in-python-3-4)

Comment: Did you intend to parse the message object - `soup = BeautifulSoup(msg, "html.parser")`?  Maybe you meant `soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")`